# How to Display list of only Directories from SFTP Server in Java

Tags: java

I'm using below code it display all files and directories. But I want only display directories. Please suggest me how to do this.

```
Properties props=new Properties();
    props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    session=jsch.getSession(username, host);
    session.setConfig(props);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    ch=(ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
    ch.connect();
it takes sftp connection    
    try
    {
        ch.cd(filepath);
    }
```

//change to current directory

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("filepath does not exists");

    }
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = ch.ls(filepath);
    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).toString()); // display all files and directories
    }

System.out.println("file is"+flagfile);

}

catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
finally
{
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'stat' method in the for loop on each entry returned by 'ls' method, which would return an object of 'SftpATTRS' which has a method called 'isDir(). This would help filter out all non-directory files.

Found that the 'ls' method returns the attributes as well. So no need to call 'stat' method. 
The following modified code snippet will print only the directories.

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = ch.ls(filepath);
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
    if (list.get(i).getAttrs().isDir()) {
      System.out.println(list.get(i).toString()); // display only directories
    }
}
```